# Partial Derivative of $\frac{\beta ^{\mathsf{T}} (A+B)\circ (A+B)}{m}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I want to take the derivative of $\frac{\beta ^{\mathsf{T}} (A+B)\circ (A+B)}{m}$ with respect to B.

However, I am getting $$\frac{2 (A+B) \beta ^{\mathsf{T}}}{m}$$

Now I believe this is wrong. But I have tried to utilize this rule: please let me know where I have gone wrong and show me how is supposed to be done, not just the answer.

$D[X\circ Y]=X\circ D[Y]+D[X]\circ Y$

Note m is a coefficient, A and B are matrices and beta is a vector.

Comment: The derivative (gradient?) of a vector-valued function wrt a matrix argument will be a 3rd order tensor. It might be simpler to consider the differential of the function, which is simply a vector $$df=\frac{2}{m}\beta^T(A+B)\circ dB$$

Comment: @greg could you please indicate some literature to get started with matrix calculus? the elegance of your answers always intrigues me. thanks in advance.

Comment: @etothepitimesi "Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives" by Are Hjorungnes is my favorite for this subject. "Matrix Differential Calculus" by Magnus & Neudecker is also good, but relies on vectorization too often for my tastes.